# How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?

Tags: software-installation, install-from-source

I have downloaded tar.gz files. But I don't know how to install it. How do I install this kind of file?

Comment: As mentioned in some of the answers below, try hard not to install packages via tarball as it will often bork managed packages and get you into in unresolvable state, and make you very sad. Installing via package manager is preferrable in 99.14159265% of cases.

Comment: There is a helpful video on YouTube which explains it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njqib0fzE9c

Comment: I tried [this](http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/untar-file-linuxubuntu/) and it worked.

Comment: Try this https://blog.bluematador.com/posts/postman-how-to-install-on-ubuntu-1604/

Comment: is this the same for ubuntu 18 or is there a UI to do it too?

Comment: Related:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/86849/how-to-unzip-a-zip-file-from-the-terminal

Answer (score 378, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is extract the files from inside the tar archive to a folder. Let's copy the files to your desktop. You can extract an archive by right-clicking the archive file's icon inside your file browser and pressing the appropriate entry in the context menu.
Extracting the archive should create a new folder with a similar name. e.g. `program-1.2.3`.
Now you need to open your terminal and navigate to that directory using the following command:

```
cd /home/yourusername/Desktop/program-1.2.3
```

Make sure you read a file called `INSTALL`, `INSTALL.txt`, `README`, or something similar if one was extracted. You can check if such a file exists from the terminal by using the `ls` command. The file can be opened and read with the command:

```
xdg-open INSTALL
```

Where INSTALL is the name of your file.
This file will contain the right steps to follow to continue the installation process. Usually, the three "classical" steps are:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

You may also need to install some dependencies if, for example, running  `configure` prompted you with an error listing which dependencies you are missing.

You can also use [`checkinstall` instead of `make install`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall).

Remember that your mileage may vary.

Comment: I would very much recommend using checkinstall, as that will make uninstalling the application much easier.

Comment: Personally I like to put source in ~/src to keep my Desktop clutter free :)

Comment: ..of course assuming the tarball contains some kind of source code.

Comment: @invert Yeah, my Windows desktop has all kinds of stuff on it: files, programs, several old, empty folders, but when I boot into Ubuntu, my desktop is *sparkling*. I have all my projects in `~/sandbox/PackageName/package-x.x-y/`

Comment: Checking for `README`s etc are also useful

Comment: That's why I wrote «Make sure you first read a file called INSTALL or INSTALL.txt or README».

Comment: these are instructions for a specific case... a more common case I run into does not require compiling, the important information to know is where in my filesystem I should move it and how to make .desktop icon file

Comment: Tarballs are used to distribute source code almost every time. If you have any specific example of unusual tarball, you may consider adding it as an answer and *that* would be a specific case.

Comment: I actually largely agree with @Selah here, almost every tarball I've come across so far is compressed binaries. Source code nowadays is distributed primarily via SCM. It would be really nice to hint at potential places to extract to for binary-tarballs, as opposed to only detailing the installation of source code (which is a ridiculous thing to begin with, really, as most developers would know what to do with it).

Comment: What kind of extremely weird tarballs do you usually download? :D

Comment: You really should promote the use of `sudo checkinstall` instead of `sudo make install` more! It's a *really* good idea to manage software compiled from source via the package management, easy removal just to mention one point. For easy dependency resolving there's `auto-apt`, see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall#Use_CheckInstall_with_auto-apt): `auto-apt run ./configure` replaces `./configure`.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Here is an example of a program that is delivered simply as a tarred directory, not as something that needs to be compiled.  https://protege.stanford.edu/products.php

Comment: This post has a nice explanation for the situation where a tar-ed program does not need to be compiled from source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/6897/where-to-install-programs

Comment: +1 but just wanted to comment that after 8 years someone should have written an automated bash script by now. The script would download, analyze, mkdir, un-tar, splash the README, check dependencies, compile, rm -d, report errors, etc. One could attach the script to `nautilus` right click. If such a script doesn't exist I may have found my next project :)

Comment: try with `sh install.sh` when `xdg-open` doesn't do

Answer (score 184):

You cannot "install" a `.tar.gz` file or .tar.bz2 file. `.tar.gz` files are gzip-compressed tarballs, compressed archives like `.zip` files. .bz2 files are compressed with bzip2. You can extract `.tar.gz` files using:

```
tar xzf file.tar.gz
```

Similarly you can extract .tar.bz2 files with

```
tar xjf file.tar.bz2
```

If you would like to see the files being extracted during unpacking, add `v`:

```
tar xzvf file.tar.gz
```

Even if you have no Internet connection, you can still use Ubuntu's package management system, just download the `.deb` files from http://packages.ubuntu.com/. Do not forget to download dependencies too.

For an easier way to install packages offline, see the question [How can I install software offline?](https://askubuntu.com/q/974/6969).

Comment: Erm.....How exactly do you download a .deb file & dependencies without an internet connection...?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning How can you post a comment here without an Internet connection...? Try the linked "How can I install software offline" link.

Comment: Sometimes there is actually _no_ need for an installation. One has only to copy/move the archived files to the right folder: First, find out where the current installation resides, e.g., via `which <SoftwareName>`. Then move the extracted contents of `tar.gz` archive to that folder to overwrite the contents.

Answer (score 81):

### How you compile a program from a source

1. Open a console
2. Use the command `cd` to navigate to the correct folder. If there is a README file with installation instructions, use that instead.
3. Extract the files with one of the commands

   - If it's **tar.gz** use `tar xvzf PACKAGENAME.tar.gz`
   - if it's a **tar.bz2** use `tar xvjf PACKAGENAME.tar.bz2`
4. `./configure`
5. `make`
6. `sudo make install` (or with [`checkinstall`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall))

### Download a package from the software sources or the software center.

If you install a package via the software sources and not downloading the package on your own, you will get new updates to that package and install them via the Update Manager.

You could just install `MYPACKAGE` by typing in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install MYPACKAGE
```

or by using the software center and searching for `MYPACKAGE`. But if it's not there go with the source.

Comment: Well, more generic instructions would be "download the file, unpack and look for install instructions either inside or on the website".

Comment: I've never got any instructions for installing from a source, I only get a folder with some install.sh or configure files. What sources do you download?

Comment: @sergey is it better now?

Comment: @Alvar: `./configure && make && sudo make install` assumes that the package uses an autoconf style of configuring and compiling programs. You should search for the files `INSTALL`, `README` or similar. Also, `make install` won't work if the prefix is set to a privileged location (which is the default). Therefore, use `sudo make install` or install it into a directory in the home directory using `./configure --prefix=~/yourprogram`. Then put `~/yourprogram/bin` in your `$PATH` or make symlinks to it in `~/bin/`.

Comment: Notice that the part about k3b is because this answer was merged from another question (which, I presume, was about installing k3b from source). So if you're **not** trying to install k3b, don't follow that! Not saying that k3b is bad though =P

Comment: what if configure file is not present?

Answer (score 37):

This is only for `.tar.*` files which have the code pre-compiled but packed into a tar file.

Okay, this is a fairly challenging task for a beginner, but just follow my instructions, and it should be fine.

First off, download the `.tar.*` file, and *save* it. Don't open it. (In these examples, I'll be installing the [Dropbox Beta build](https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=91315), because I was going to install it anyway, so I figured that I might as well document the installation.)

After you've downloaded your file, (assuming that you saved it to `Downloads`,) type the following:

```
cd Downloads
sudo cp dropbox-lnx.x86_64-1.5.36.tar.gz /opt/
```

NOTE: use the name of whatever file you downloaded. (e.g., for the Firefox Nightly 19.0a1 64-bit build, you would type `sudo cp firefox-19.0a1.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 /opt/`)

Now, change to the `/opt/` directory, extract the program, and remove the old file:

```
cd /opt/
sudo tar -xvf dropbox-lnx.x86_64-1.5.36.tar.gz
sudo rm -rf dropbox-lnx.x86_64-1.5.36.tar.gz
```

(again, use the name of the downloaded file. Don't forget the extension.)

Okay, check to see what the extracted folder is called:

```
ls -a
```

you'll get something like this:

```
james@james-OptiPlex-GX620:/opt$ ls -a
.  ..  .dropbox-dist
james@james-OptiPlex-GX620:/opt$
```

Okay, in our example, we installed Dropbox, and the only folder there is called `.dropbox-dist`. That's probably the folder we want, so plug that in to the next step (add a `/` to the end, since it's a folder.):

```
sudo chmod 777 .dropbox-dist/
```

Okay, it's now marked as executable, so it's time to create a symbolic link (this is what allows you to run it from the Terminal):

```
sudo ln -s /opt/.dropbox-dist/ /usr/bin/dropbox
```

NOTE: this is `sudo ln -s /opt/{FOLDER_NAME}/ /usr/bin/{PROGRAM_NAME}`!!! Be sure that `{PROGRAM_NAME}` is replaced with the simplified, lower-case version of the program's name (e.g., for Firefox Nightly, type `firefox-nightly`; for the uTorrent server, type `utserver`. Whatever you type here will be the command that you use whenever running the program from the Terminal. Think of `/usr/bin/` as like the PATH variable on Windows systems.)

Okay, you're done. The program is now installed and runnable from the Terminal.
What's this? You say you want to run it from the launcher, AND you want it to have an icon? No problem!

This part is fairly simple:

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop
```

NOTE: If you're installing OVER a previous installation, use `ls -a /usr/share/applications` and search for pre-existing .desktop file. Plug that file's name in instead.

Now, here's where you create the icon. Here's good template; edit it appropriately.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Firefox Nightly
Comment=Browse the World Wide Web
GenericName=Web Browser
Keywords=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer
Exec=firefox-nightly
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=/opt/firefox/icons/mozicon128.png
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;application/rss+xml;application/rdf+xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;x-scheme-handler/chrome;video/webm;application/x-xpinstall;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=NewWindow;

[Desktop Action NewWindow]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=firefox-nightly -new-window
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

You may want to leave off the MimeType option completely. That could be very bad if you didn't.

Now, click "Save", close it out, and you're in business!

Comment: I think this isn't a good answer, because you don't differentiate between software that you have as binary and software in source code.

Comment: Think you are getting the down votes because you are not explaining what to do with most source code packed file you download. Just because dropbox came on a nice binary ready to be extracted to `/opt` that does not mean that every application will be delivered that way, specially since dropbox is closed source. This does not explain how to pick up a source package, build it and install it as it is.

Comment: What does "Okay, it's now marked as executable, so it's time to create a symbolic link (**this is what allows you to run it from the Terminal**)" mean?

Comment: sudo ln -s /opt/{FOLDER_NAME}/ etc. shoud be sudo ln -s /opt/{FOLDER_NAME}/{program real name} ? etc.

Comment: So does `cp dropbox-lnx.x86_64-1.5.36.tar.gz /opt/` unpack the archive automatically?

Answer (score 22):

#### First things first

It is generally *not* advised to download and install applications from the internet files. Most applications for Ubuntu are available through the "Ubuntu Software Center" on your system (for example, [K3B](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/k3b) [image: Install K3B]). Installing from the Software Center is much more secure, much easier, and will allow the app to get updates from Ubuntu.

#### That said, how to install `tar` packages

The best way is to download the tar.bz2 and tar.gz packages to your system first. Next is to rightclick on the file and select extract to decompress the files. Open the location of the folder you extracted and look for the **Readme** file and double click to open it and follow the instruction on how to install the particular package because, there could be different instruction available for the proper installation of the file which the normal routine might not be able to forestall without some errors.

Answer (score 17):

First of all it is important to install the package [build-essential](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/build-essential), it contains all programs needed to compile on your own.

After reading the INSTALL file as stated above and fulfilling the prerequisites you can do the magic.

```
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

Answer (score 12):

It is difficult to answer specifically, as each software may have a different build process, even if they are archived as a TAR/GZ

What I can say for most source codes that I know of is that you will first need to extract the tarball archive into a folder of your choice. Then most source codes rely on the AUTOCONF and MAKE programs, so you will need to use the following commands :

```
./configure
make
```

To build your binaries, and then :

```
make install
```

To install it in the system.

"./configure" uses the autoconf mechanism to retrieve information on your system, and prepare the build scripts in the source file in order to build the appropriate binaries compatible with your installation.
 "make" will invode the build itself, that will create the binaries out of the source code.
 "make install" will then copy the binaries, documentation, configuration file, etc. into the appropriate folders of your system so that the software is available to the users.

It is a very basic explanation, the real answer is : read the documentation provided with the source code... Only there you will know exactly how to build it.

Answer (score 8):

You should always try to install software from repositories whether it's official, a PPA/any other unofficial repository. That way, you'll get all stable release, security and new feature updates while you install other system updates. Another advantage is that you don't need to worry about building, dependencies and harder uninstallation (since the application won't appear in synaptic) with tar files.

For example, you can install mysql by installing mysql-server package.

If you really want to use tar files, the common process is to run (make install may require sudo):

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Please note that some of the above commands may not be necessary, please refer to any readme files in the tar file or try to run `./configure --help`

Answer (score 8):

Files with the extension `tar.bz2` are what is commonly known as a `compressed tarball`.
Other examples are `.tar.gz` (more common) and `.tgz`.

You can extract this file with...

```
tar -xvjf file.tar.bz2
```

This will extract the files from the tarball into the directory you are currently in and should create a new directory there with in that the files from the tarball.

Short explanation on the options:

- -x : extract
- -v : verbose: show what is being extracted
- -j : type of compression, in this case `bzip2`
- -f : 'next comes the filename'

This is probably not enough though. Depending on what it is it could have a complete compiled setup and you need to cd into the new directory and start an executable. It could also contain the source to a program that you need to confire, make, make install.
Generally (ie. I would assume) it should contain a readme that explains what to do next.

Warning:

Installing software like this will NOT install any dependencies and will complain if you try to install a tarball before you installed these dependencies.
Use a website or the file itself to find out if there are dependencies and install those first. But always always always first try to find a `.DEB`ian installation file or a link to a `ppa` so you can use ubuntu software center.

---

If you are trying to install the gimp plugins you skipped parts of the installation process mentioned [in this link](http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/19345/gimp-28-with-single-window-mode/).

```
wget ftp://ftp.gtk.org/pub/babl/0.1/babl-0.1.10.tar.bz2
tar -xvf babl-0.1.10.tar.bz2
cd babl-0.1.10/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

and you will also need `gegl`:

```
wget ftp://ftp.gimp.org/pub/gegl/0.2/gegl-0.2.0.tar.bz2
tar -xvf gegl-0.2.0.tar.bz2
cd gegl-0.2.0/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Before downloading the files with wget visit the website and see if it has newer versions. These instructions are from the 3rd of May 2012 so they could be old ;)

Comment: I ran `tar -xvjf` and then `./configure` and I got an error message, see my edit in the original post.

Comment: Yes. Also, I did that and got another error, please see my second edit in the original post.

Comment: Could you rephrase that?

Comment: you installed babl. the 1st time you got an error it ONLY complained about babl. so try to configure the 1st tarball (the one that complained about babl) it might work now.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Judging by the tutorial you linked to in your post, I'm presuming there's a lot more I need to do, though. This is all way over my head so I guess I'll just wait for a .deb. Thanks for your help, though!

Answer (score 7):

### From the official website of Linux Mint

#### Installing from archives (.zip tar.gz, etc.):

These archives generally contain the source of the package. Each of them generally has a different approach to install. I will be discussing a common method which will supposedly work for all of them.

General requirements:

1. flex
2. bison or bison++
3. python

As these archives contains the source, your system needs the required programming languages to compile and build the source. So the general requirement packages stated above may not be sufficient for you. In that case you have to install the required packages through one of the processes #1,#2,#3 (requires internet connection). You can know about the dependencies about your software in a readme file included in the archives.

Steps:

1. open the archives with archive manager by double clicking it, then extract it.
2. code:

cd path-to-the-extracted-folder

3. inside the extracted folder look carefully....

#### a. If you find a file named configure then

```
./configure    
make
sudo make install
```

If the first code fails to execute then run this code before above codes:

```
chmod +x configure
```

#### b. If you find a file named install.sh then

Code:

```
chmod +x install.sh
```

`./install.sh` or `sudo ./install.sh` (if it needs root permission)

or you can double click it and select run in terminal or simply run.

N.B.: sometimes there is a file, something like `your_software_name.sh` is found instead of `install.sh`. For this case, you have to replace `install.sh` with the correct name in the previous codes.

#### c. If you find a file named install then

code:

```
chmod +x install
```

`./install` or `sudo ./install` (if it needs root permission)

or you can double click it and select run in terminal or simply run.

#### d. If you find a file named make (if there is no configure file) then

code:

```
make
sudo make install
```

#### e. If you still can't find the required files

then it may be in a special folder (generally in a folder named `bin`). Move to this folder with `cd` command with the appropriate path and then look again and follow the same process.

Answer (score 3):

Before compilation of extracted tar.gz-, tar.bz2-, tar.xz-archives you should do the following:

1. At first you should check existence of Ubuntu package for the application, which you are trying to compile.
   For example if you are trying to compile *Empathy* you should search package archive for it on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) for your release (or for [all releases](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=empathy)).
   The results for *Empathy*:

   > Package empathy
   >
   > - trusty (14.04LTS) (gnome): GNOME multi-protocol chat and call client
   >     3.8.6-0ubuntu9: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el
   > - trusty-updates (gnome): GNOME multi-protocol chat and call client
   >     3.8.6-0ubuntu9.2: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el
   > - xenial (16.04LTS) (gnome): GNOME multi-protocol chat and call client [**universe**]
   >     3.12.11-0ubuntu3: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el s390x
   > - artful (gnome): GNOME multi-protocol chat and call client [**universe**]
   >     3.25.90+really3.12.14-0ubuntu1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
   > - bionic (gnome): GNOME multi-protocol chat and call client [**universe**]
   >     3.25.90+really3.12.14-0ubuntu1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
2. Then install build-essential package with

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential
   ```
3. As we know that packages have dependencies (both on execution and on compilation), so we need to install compile time dependencies (also known as build-dependencies). You should enable *Source code* repositories (*deb-src*) in *Software & Updates* (`software-properties-gtk`) and then run

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep empathy
   ```
4. Then you can extract downloaded source archive and try to compile it in usual way

   ```
   wget http://ftp.gnome.org/mirror/gnome.org/sources/empathy/3.25/empathy-3.25.90.tar.xz
   tar -xf empathy-3.25.90.tar.xz
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install # or better - checkinstall
   ```

   ***Note:*** in this example `./configure` stage will fail on Ubuntu Xenial (16.04 LTS) because of the fact that library versions dependencies are not satisfied.
   In that case you have two options - use older pre-compiled packaged version from repository, try to find newer version in PPAs or upgrade whole Ubuntu to next release (preferably LTS).

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the package contains a runnable file with the same name of the software. You can just run that on the terminal.

```
$ ./Software-Name
```

Answer (score 2):

Often programs that are offered as tar.gz files do not need to be compiled from source; they just need to be unzipped, stuck in the appropriate directory, and linked to an executable path.  Here are some example commands I used today.

```
tar -xzf ~/Downloads/Newprogram.tar.gz
sudo mv Newprogram/ /usr/local/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/Newprogram/run.sh /usr/local/bin/newprogram.sh
```

The directories I used were informed by this post: 
[Where to install programs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6897/where-to-install-programs)

Answer (score -1):

In this answer I am going to install one sample package ie. vlc for your reference but, before we go further I would like to give some information.

If you have used Windows you might come in contact with WinRAR,7-Zip, etc.
and for Android RAR, Zarchiver, etc.

tar (TapeArchiver)is one kind of compression software. It makes an archive of files and folders but not compress them.

As archiver softwares have various mode such as

- `gz` best speed with regular compression.
- `bz` somewhere mid between regular compression and medium speed.
- `xz` is better compression but poor speed.

Now come to the installation part!

first you must have tarball

1. Lets download it
   `wget http://get.videolan.org/vlc/3.0.8/vlc-3.0.8.tar.xz -c`

here -c is for continue download (for your reference)
2. Extract package
`tar -xvf vlc-3.0.8.tar.xz`

here x is extract, v for verbose, f for Regular file
3. Install package
go to extracted directory `cd vlc-3.0.8`

> ./configure

Here is one issue is that you need to configure your linux pc for make sure that its dependency will get resolved
so that you need to install some dependencies as follows

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential 
sudo apt-get install pkg-config libtool automake 
sudo apt-get install autopoint gettext
sudo apt-get install libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb-xv0-dev 
sudo apt-get install libxcb-keysyms1-dev libxcb-randr0-dev 
sudo apt-get install libxcb-composite0-dev
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends build-dep vlc
```

> make

> make install

if these commands run successfully, your vlc will be installed.

then run it by:

> ./vlc

Thanks..

Comment: As Petri Hintukainen claims one needs to install libblrray-master with a fix before libbluray 1.3.2 is released (see https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libbluray/-/issues/38), it would be good to see how to install VLC in Ubuntu where it does not complain when default-jre is installed (in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS)