# installing programs under root

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, software-installation, root

I'm new to Ubuntu, and I've been a bit confused about where to install new programs...

The answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/6903/) says:

> If the program needs to create a folder, then /usr/local is the directory of choice; according to the FHS:
>
> > The /usr/local hierarchy is for use by the system administrator when
> >     installing software locally.

Furthermore, most references I've read (e.g. [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PartitioningSchemes)) say that the root partition should be ~30 GB.

My problem is that if I want to install memory intensive programs (e.g. MATLAB, Mathematica etc.), this really doesn't seem like enough memory for me... I guess I'm just confused as to why the recommendation is so low. Furthermore, [this article here](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/35676/how-to-choose-a-partition-scheme-for-your-linux-pc/) (maybe a bit dated?) claims that 25-35% of the root partition should be left as free space for "self-cleaning" purposes. With the OS taking ~6 GB, I just don't understand how this can satisfy any user's needs. Is it because most programs are far below the memory needs of the more memory intensive programs I mentioned?

Any help is greatly appreciated :D

Comment: What exactly is your question

Comment: I guess I'm just confused about the suggestion to allocate 30 GB to the root partition... is it normal to need a lot more? Also, should I really be installing heavy programs like MATLAB in `/usr/local`?

Comment: Depend on what programs you are going to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most users install programs via command (sudo apt install firefox) or via software.center|ubuntu.software which automatically installs the program to wherever the .deb file dicated.  It's sort of similar with snaps (though they stay as squashfs & aren't installed to your actual filesystem [fs])

Most people's programs aren't that huge; its the data that takes all the space. User data on an ubuntu will generally go to /home/

The /usr is commonly where apt-get|apt|etc will install a program; and its the unix (*nix) default place (ie. historically been put there since '80s if not 1970s)

You can install programs wherever you want!  But when you upgrade; remember where you installed it so it can be backed up & restored.  I install many things in /usr/local/bin out of habit; but others go inside /home as I find it easier to recover if I have problems (/home is on different drives for many of my systems, at least different partition, thus allows me to replace system drive & clean-install but keep).  Also you can choose to use a filesystem that allows growing|shrinking during operation which is more used by servers or mission critical systems.

---

Note:  don't mix up /root & the / directories. 
/root/ refers to the 'root' user directory (equivalent is /home/root/ if it wasn't a special user),
and '/' which is the top or root directory.
my "/" directory is on a small 160gb drive; but i've mounted many tb of directories onto it so the partition & drive sizes mean little.

Comment: Good answer overall, but it makes it sound as if the snap format was free in terms of disk space. It's not; the files still have to go somewhere on the disk. Also, third-party applications that are *not* distributed via Debian packages traditionally go somewhere in `/opt`. This directory and `/usr/local` are similar in purpose, but `/opt` is for precompiled stuff you get from wherever, whereas `/usr/local` is for things you compile yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was wondering why exactly the FHS recommends installing programs to `/usr/local`, is there any particular advantage to doing this, over perhaps installing on `/home`?

Comment: I usually have my `/home` on a different partition (or drive) so if I need to re-install or change OS for any reason, I don't lose my data (inc. programs) in `/home` (letting it install only to `/` partition and adding the `/home` mount to `/etc/fstab` myself later).   Ubuntu unlike some distros is very good at trying to avoid format unless necessary, which is part of why I like `/home` for stuff

`whereis` can tell you were apps are located, but keeping apps out of `/home` can simplify backups as programs don't change as much.