# Where does Ubuntu (or Linux in general) install its applications?

Tags: software-installation

In Windows, all installed applications go into the Program Files/Program Files(x86) of the hard-drive in which the application is installed on.

What is the equivalent in Linux or Ubuntu specifically?

When I install a program using APT, flatpacks, snaps or using manual methods such as .deb among others - where should I be installing these? Or do these methods automatically follow a convention?

Additional small question:
Does the same convention apply to servers?

Comment: Use `dpkg -L <package_name>` to see where deb files are installed to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to install programs?](https://askubuntu.com/q/6897)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packages, whether on a Server or Desktop edition, generally follow the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html) of the [Linux Foundation](https://www.linuxfoundation.org/) which has an illustrated overview at https://www.howtogeek.com/117435/htg-explains-the-linux-directory-structure-explained/ . [Appimages](https://appimage.org/), [flatpacks](https://flatpak.org/), and [snaps](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/basic-snap-usage#1-introduction) may deviate further from the standard than do apps installed through [apt](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt.8.html).