# How to create a server system on ubuntu-16.04?

Tags: server, permissions

I was working on server as admin and five standard users were also connecting.
However, when I installed a new package (like numpy etc.), they couldn't use it. I needed to change many things on server or bashrc files etc..

Now, I'm creating a new server on ubuntu-16.04 (as admin) and want to create a standard users or a group that includes all standard users. 
I want to make accessible all programs(that will be installed) without any sudo permission (or changing any paths) for standard users(or group).

How to build this kind of system?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to install software and executables for all users](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65728/where-to-install-software-and-executables-for-all-users)

Answer (score 0):

All versions of **Ubuntu** and **Ubuntu Server** as well as all flavors of Linux is the type of system you described.

The main difference between **Ubuntu Desktop** and **Ubuntu Server** is that the server version installs a striped down version allowing the Administrator to pick out many packages that he prefers to install, such as the GUI desktop.

The users on the system will have access to the applications that you install system-wide.  Applications installed from the repository using the Software Center or `apt` are installed system-wide.

If you install an application outside of a **deb** distribution, it would depend on how you install it.  If you compile a program, under normal circumstances the program is compiled (and should be for security) in the user's personal space, by a normal account without elevated access.

When it's time to install the complied package, many distributors of the packages will include a `make install` option, that when run using the elevated `sudo` command, will install the package system-wide.  If it doesn't place the package system wide, it's something you would have to do manually.

You mentioned one program, `numpy`.  However, it would depend on the one program how you installed it.  If you would be specific for a program you are having problems, you would have to include the steps you used for installing that program, so that you can have suggestions of how to make that particular program system wide.  Once you do this for one or two programs, you can use the same method to do this for all your programs.

It might not be the one you are looking for, but **python-numpy** is available via the repository.  If you install it with this command:

```
 $ sudo apt install python-numpy
```

It'll be available system wide.

As far as **users and permission and access to programs**, creating a user by default will give the users that type of access and permission that you describe in your question.

All the users have access to programs that are in the same folders that you have access to by default.  Use this command to see which paths are searched:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

You may consider placing your programs in a subdirectory of `/opt`.  Then place a link to that program's execute file in a default path such as `usr/local/bin`.

If you have a program called `saytime.sh`, you can place it into `/opt/timeprogram/saytime.sh`.

Then place a link to that program in `/usr/local/bin` using this command:

```
$ ln -s /opt/timeprogram/saytime.sh
```

Now the program can be run from the commandline without having to navigate to the location of the program, and not having to type a full path to the program.

For creating an Ubuntu Server, just download the server version the same way you downloaded the Desktop version.  Install it the same way.  But as I mentioned above, the behavior of both are the same when it comes to the criteria of your question.