# Where to place local executables

Tags: .profile, binary

Where is the correct place to store user-local executable files?

`echo $PATH` gives

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

It doesn't include eg. `$HOME/bin`

Would `$HOME/bin` be advisable? Or `$HOME/opt/bin` ....

I guess I would have to add that to my .profile too?

Comment: Do not change anything, just `mkdir ~/bin`, log out and log back in and it'll be there.

Comment: Be sure to make all directories in you `PATH` non-writable, as writable bin directories are a major security hole.

Comment: If this is just for the user, then binaries can be placed in `~/.local/bin`. My PATH didn't include this location when it was empty. But I added a binary to it, rebooted, and it was automatically added to `$PATH`. If it's for all users of the machine, then `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think if you add a $HOME/bin directory it should be added to the path automatically, looking in my .profile would indicate this

Yes just checked and by creating a $HOME/bin directory the next time you log in its automatically added to the path.

Hope that helps

Comment: BTW if you jut created this folder you will need to source .profile file in order to make new adde binary to be availible using $PATH : # source ~/.profile

Answer (score 6):

Based-on what you are describing, I'm thinking that you should install your executables to `/usr/local/bin/`.

Here is an answer to a similar question that backs-up this assessment:  [What is the best place to install user apps?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148/what-is-the-best-place-to-install-user-apps/1150#1150)

Otherwise, you certainly could create a `~/bin` directory and add it to your path.  IMO that is a viable solution if those apps will/should be used only by your user.  But you will run into some security headaches if another user has a need for those apps later on.

Comment: I share my laptop, on which I am hacking, with my wife. she will probably never need on of my executables. Thank's for your security concerns though!