# How to install ionic-lab on Ubuntu 14.04 and run app?

Tags: software-installation

I have installed ionic on my ubuntu desktop and created an app now I want to install ionic-lab, I have downloaded ionic-lab but cannot understand how to install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really simple :)

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

1. Download `ionic-lab` :

   ```
   wget http://ionic-io-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/labs/IonicLab-linux-x64.tar.gz
   ```
2. Extract `IonicLab-linux-x64.tar.gz` archive.
3. Open `ionic-lab` by double clicking on the file named **IonicLab**. That's it.

---

If you need to install it, please refer to this question : [What is the best place to install user apps?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1148/338915)

Comment: Its not showing GUI like windows.

Comment: Do you have any error ? For me it show the GUI without problem on Ubuntu 15.10.