# Ubuntu 20.04 Remove items from application list

Tags: gnome-shell, .desktop, activities-overview

### Environment

Ubuntu 20.04

### Problem

I am trying to remove these links without luck. I have tried to find them as .desktop files.

**Case 1**: Duplicated link.

[image]

**Case 2**: Unneeded link. "Additional drivers"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bit difficult task to know the `.desktop` files of the applications that are shown in overview..

But once you know the application file names.. Its easy to hide them..
for example, I have struggled to get the Additional Drivers... file. Once I came to know that this is the file `/usr/share/applications/software-properties-drivers.desktop` have edited like below.. added this line `NoDisplay=true`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Keywords=Drivers;
Exec=/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4
Icon=jockey
Terminal=false
Type=Application
NotShowIn=KDE;
Categories=X-XFCE;GTK;Settings;HardwareSettings
X-AppStream-Ignore=true
Name=Additional Drivers
Comment=Configure third-party and proprietary drivers
X-AppStream-Ignore=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=software-properties

NoDisplay=true
```

[image]

[image]

so in the similar way you can achieve for "Kolourpaint" also.
a basic way to search is `ls /usr/share/applications/ | grep Kolour` or change the word Kolour with paint etc..

for snap install you may need to check in this directory

```
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications
```

Further Reading: [Open](https://askubuntu.com/q/1148/739431)

Comment: Additional Drivers was very easy to find with your help. However I still can't find KolourPaint on either /usr/share/applications or $HOME/.local/share/applications. So it is probably somewhere else.

Comment: how did you install Kolourpaint.. so that I can install in same way and search it..

Comment: This issue is coming from an ugrade 18.04 > 20.04. I think I installed KolourPaint on 18.04 via apt-get. And on 20.04 via application manager GUI.

Comment: Yes, KolourPaint is in `/var/snap/`. Both desktop links start KolourPaint up correctly but I would like to know how can I delete the one with generic icon which is duplicated.

Comment: did you check in `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications` probably you will get it there..

Comment: Perfect!! I found there two files: `kolourpaint_org.kde.kolourpaint.desktop`  and 
`kolourpaint_kolourpaint.desktop`. I added `NoDisplay=true` in the first one and issue solved. Thanks.